# Platform independent way to set or clear a bit in Linux Kernel

Tags: c, linux-kernel

I'm currently reading through Robert Love's *Linux Kernel Development*, Third Edition and I encountered an odd statement after a section explaining the `set_bit()`, `clear_bit()` atomic functions and their non-atomic siblings, `__set_bit()` and `__clear_bit()`:

> Unlike the atomic integer operations, code typically has no choice whether to use the bitwise operations—they are the **only portable way to set a specific bit.**

-p. 183 (emphasis my own)

I understand that these operations can be implemented in a single platform-specific assembly instruction, which is why these inline functions exist.  But I'm curious as to why the author said that these are the *only* portable ways to do these things.  For instance, I believe I could non-atomically set bit `nr` in `unsigned long x` by doing this in plain C:

```
x |= 1UL << nr;
```

Similarly I can non-atomically clear bit `nr` in `unsigned long x` by doing this:

```
x &= ~(1UL << nr);
```

Of course, depending on the sophistication of the compiler, these may compile to several instructions, and so they may not be as nice as the `__set_bit()` and `__clear_bit()` functions.

Am I missing something here?  Was this phrase just a slightly lazy simplification, or is there something unportable about the ways I've presented above for setting and clearing bits?

**Edit:** It appears that, although GCC is pretty sophisticated, it still performs the bit shifts instead of using a single instruction like the `__set_bit()` function does, even on `-O3` (version 6.2.1).  As an example:

```
stephen at greed in ~/code 
$ gcc -g -c set.c -O3         

stephen at greed in ~/code 
$ objdump -d -M intel -S set.o

set.o:     file format elf64-x86-64


Disassembly of section .text.startup:

0000000000000000 <main>:
#include<stdio.h>
int main(int argc, char *argv)
{
  unsigned long x = 0;
  x |= (1UL << argc);
   0:   89 f9                   mov    ecx,edi
   2:   be 01 00 00 00          mov    esi,0x1
   7:   48 83 ec 08             sub    rsp,0x8
   b:   48 d3 e6                shl    rsi,cl
   e:   bf 00 00 00 00          mov    edi,0x0
  13:   31 c0                   xor    eax,eax
  15:   e8 00 00 00 00          call   1a <main+0x1a>
{
  1a:   31 c0                   xor    eax,eax
  x |= (1UL << argc);
  1c:   48 83 c4 08             add    rsp,0x8
  printf("x=%x\n", x);
  20:   c3                      ret
```

Comment: This is UB if you shift into the sign-bit of the (`signed`) `long`.

Comment: Fair point -- the kernel operations are defined on `void *` but I decided to use integers for simplicity.  I'll change them to `unsigned long`.

Comment: Your edit changes nothing. `1L <<  nr` is done at `signed long` type, regardless of what type you assign the result to.

Comment: Alright, so the literals ought to be `1UL << nr` instead of `1L`.  I think we're kind of missing the point with this line of edits, but I'll fix it :)

Comment: "sophistication of the compiler" - We're talking about the Linux kernel here. It _will_ be a sophisticated compiler; Linux has too many non-standard constructs for an ordinary compiler. In fact, it either has to be GCC or look like GCC.

Comment: Now if you want to set a specific bit in a `signed long`, you are in trouble, because if the bit you want to set is the sign-bit, the code you have posted causes *implementation defined behavior*.

Comment: With `x &= ~(1UL << nr);`, nothing prevents an interrupt or other process from getting in the middle of the read of `x` and the write of `x` as code is not atomic,

Comment: @chux: very true, but I read the quote as meaning that this was the only portable way to do it even for the *non-atomic* versions.

Comment: @MSalters: Check my updated question to see how GCC appears to treat these expressions on `-O3`

Comment: @brenns10: Might want to include `__set_bit()` for comparison.

Comment: The "they" in "...  _they_ are the only portable way to set a specific bit." is referring to "bitwise operations".  You code is doing "bitwise operations" with `x |= 1UL << nr;`. So no, there is not "something unportable about the ways I've presented above for setting and clearing bits?"  Is this close to answering your question (which I am not sufficiently confident of understanding.)

Comment: If you look at what those function does you will find out `nr` is not restricted to a single word. So the portability problems of word size, alignment requirement all appliy here. Also if you look at the actual implementations you will see quite a few platforms tries to "optimize" it by reducing the amount of "read-modify-write" to shorter data types such as `char` or `int`. IMO a generic implementation that "read-modify-write"s on a `long *` is very portable but has a potential performance disadvantage on LP64 platforms (all/most 64-bit platforms supported by Linux)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the context of *atomic* integer operations, "bitwise operations" also means the atomic ones.

There is nothing special about the non-atomic bitwise operations (except that they support numbers larger than BITS_PER_LONG), so the [generic implementation](http://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/include/asm-generic/bitops/non-atomic.h) is always correct, and architecture-specific implementations would be needed only to optimize performance.

Comment: Very nice, I never knew that those generic implementations existed.